# How do I convert a Tendril<UTF8> to &str or String?

Tags: rust, html5ever

I'm using HTML5ever, and I'm trying to put attributes into a `Vec<(String, String>)` (although `(&str, &str)` would work too).

Unfortunately, [html5ever's attribute values are in `Tendril<UTF8>`s](https://docs.rs/html5ever/0.22.2/html5ever/tree_builder/struct.Attribute.html), not `String`s (or `QualName`s, `&str`s, etc.). How can I convert one of these `Tendril`s into a `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use its `Deref` implementation:

```
extern crate tendril;

use tendril::{fmt::UTF8, Tendril};

fn example(t: &Tendril<UTF8>) -> &str {
    t
}

fn main() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like this

```
    //the value is Tendril<UTF8> type 
    String::from(value);
```